# Why is there a lengthy stack of line breaks being inserted in the middle of the product description in Magento?

Tags: html, magento-1.9

I run this in MySQL Workbench:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_text 
SET `value` = '
<p>2 Non-pleated Fitted Tablecloth, also called box style. This fitted cover 
style with no pleating has become popular and stylish in the past year.</p>
<p><br /> <strong><span style="color: #ff0000;">FITTED TABLECLOTH OPTIONS<br 
/></span><span style="color: #ff0000;">Option 1</span></strong>&nbsp;Four 
sided fitted. Covers the top and all four sides to the floor.&nbsp;</p>
<p><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>Option 2</strong></span>&nbsp;Three 
sided fitted. Covers the top and three sides of the table. Back side it 
drapes 10". Ideal for situations such as reception booth, trade shows or 
convention where someone will be seated at the table.&nbsp;<br /><br />
<strong><span style="color: #ff0000;"> Option 3&nbsp;</span></strong>Four 
sided fitted with slit(s). Covers the top and all four sides of table to the  
floor. The back side has a hidden slit in one back corner for partial access 
to storage underneath the table or choose 2 slits for complete, easy access 
under the table. With the 2 slits (one in each back corner), the entire back 
panel lifts.<br /><br /> <span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>Option 
4</strong></span> NEW&nbsp;Four sided with 4 hidden slits, one in each of 
the four corners. Ideal for dining or for when guest will be seated at the 
table. Guest can now easily and comfortably be seated and slide their chairs 
in. Many Wedding Professionals, venues and banquet halls had requested this 
option to provide an upscale alternative to just using a tablecloth. We 
listened.</p>
<p><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>PRODUCTION TIME</strong></span> <br 
/> Up to 50 pieces, only 24-hour production time. 50+ to 99 units 48-hours. 
100+ 72 hours.</p>
<p><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>WASHING, FOLDING, STORAGE</strong>
</span><br /> Machine wash cool, tumble dry low heat. Can be laundered in 
noncommercial machine at home or commercial washer or dry cleaned.&nbsp; 
Tumble dry, remove from dryer promptly and follow directions on image below 
to fold and avoid wrinkles. </p>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1. Use a flat surface or friend to pop in the side pleats</td>
      <td>2. Lay flat to start rolling</td>
      <td>3. Continue to fold in the flat panels to the desired width</td>
      <td>4. Hang over a sturdy hanger</td>
      <td>5. Store in a basket, on a shelf or back into the zippered plastic 
bag</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;<br /> <span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>COLORS 74</strong>
</span> Colors available.</p>
<iframe style="max-width: 100%;" width="600" height="430" style="max-width: 
100%;" src="//www.cincopa.com/media-platform/iframe.aspx?fid=A4LAfH-jkbhG" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" scrolling="yes"></iframe><br>'
WHERE entity_id IN (SELECT product_id FROM catalog_category_product WHERE
category_id IN (571, 570))
AND attribute_id = 57;
```

Between the upper text and the table it's inserting 17 `<br>` tags, only on page render. They're not in the description source in the product editor. It's wherever I place the table. Why?

Comment: You can't smash that query in there without proper escaping. If you're not prepared to escape it, directly edit the row without running an `UPDATE` query. You can usually double-click on the row to edit data directly based on the result of a `SELECT * FROM table_name` type query provided that table has a `PRIMARY KEY` column.

Comment: I don't know what you're referring to, tadman. It's Magento that was doing it. Anyway I just used div styled display:table instead.

Comment: Well, okay then.